# The For Loop is not working in an appropriate way (Angular2)

Tags: loops, for-loop, typescript, angular

I'm wondering why am i getting a weird behavior using `For` Loop in `Angular2 (TypeScript)`. I made this loop

```
 loadAllQuestions() {

            this.questionService.loadAllQuestions()
                .map(res=>res.json())
                .subscribe(res=>{
                    this.listQuestion = res.questions;
                    for (var q in this.listQuestion){
                        this.propositionService.findPropositionByQuestion(this.listQuestion[q].wordingQ)
                            .map(res=>res.json())
                            .subscribe(res=>{
                                console.log(this.listQuestion[q]);
                            });
                    }
           });
     }
```

So that for every `Question` (in `listQuestion`) I called a service that would find all the propositions for this question (`findPropositionByQuestion`) using its wording (`wordingQ`) ; the problem is that it seems the loop  is not working , when making the `console.log(this.listQuestion[q])` it shows off only the last Question in the `listQuestion` duplicated as much as the number of the indexes in the listQuestion (so if i have 3 Questions, it shows me the last Question 3 times and so on..).
For more explication:  here i have 2 loaded Questions :

[image]

And here what the console.log is showing me :

[image]

Any Help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your code with an additional method:

```
loadAllQuestions() {
  this.questionService.loadAllQuestions()
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.listQuestion = res.questions;
      for (var q in this.listQuestion) {
        this.findProposition(this.listQuestion[q]);
      }
    };
}

findProposition(question) {                          
  this.propositionService.findPropositionByQuestion(
    question.wordingQ)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(question);
        console.log(res);
      });
}
```

This question could help you to understand why you have several times the same element displayed in trace:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

You can make `q` variable block scoped using [`let`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) keyword.

```
for (let q in this.listQuestion){ //var --> let
    this.propositionService
        .findPropositionByQuestion(this.listQuestion[q].wordingQ)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(res=>{
            console.log(this.listQuestion[q]);
         });
}
```

Comment: Here it required Emascript 6 or higher, Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Selem Like if arrow functions don't :) You are using typescript anyway. Doesn't it handle let to var transformation for you?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=for%20(let%20q%20in%20obj)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomethingAsync(res%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%5Bq%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: no as i told you ; an error occured :  Emascript 6 or higher is required :) (i liked your answer ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try `for (var q of this.listQuestion){...}` instead of `for (var q in this.listQuestion){...}`